# ECL Adapter and SDL Web 8 - How is ECL Dll linked to SDL Web 8

Tags: web8, configuration, ecl

I am unable to find the configuration setting, where my ECL dll is referred to from the SDL CM side.

I have checked, and its not there in the `Tridion.ContentManager.config`.

Is there any standard. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check this doc http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-6127E254-2754-41E0-992C-5ADF18296775#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-948FBBE8-6127-4943-981F-BB2FDF87C2C6.xml&docid=GUID-948FBBE8-6127-4943-981F-BB2FDF87C2C6&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-948FBBE8-6127-4943-981F-BB2FDF87C2C6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mountpoints configured in ExternalContentLibrary.xml

Every mountpoint element has attribute **type** (e.g type="My Custom Provider")

Every provider has main class that implements **IContentLibrary**

And this class must have attribute **AddIn**
(e.g [AddIn("My Custom Provider", Version = "1.0.0.0")])

Name in AddIn attribute in class matched with **type** attribute in mountpoint xml, and this how ECL find proper dll for particular mountpoint.

Example:

In ExternalContentLibrary.xml

```
    <MountPoint type="My Custom Provider" id="mcp" rootItemName="Test">
```

In main class of provider

```
    [AddIn("My Custom Provider", Version = "1.2.0.0")]
    public class MyProvider : IContentLibrary
    {
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, those settings are available in the `ExternalContentLibrary.xml` file under

`C:\{SDLWEB Installation Folder}\Config\`

You can find mount points for each of your ECL links,
Example:

```
<MountPoint type="Local File System Provider" id="ffs1" rootItemName="Digital Assets Management">
  <StubFolders>
    <StubFolder id="tcm:1-633-2" />
    <StubFolder id="tcm:8-733-2" />
  </StubFolders>
  <PrivilegedUserName>SDLPE\SDL</PrivilegedUserName>
  <FolderPath>C:\Working Areas\ECL\DAM</FolderPath>
  <IconIdentifier>DamLibrary</IconIdentifier>
  <IconURL>http://tridion.sdldemo.com/WebUI/Editors/CME/Themes/Carbon/Images/ECLIcons/</IconURL>
</MountPoint>
```

Hope this helps to make changes to ECL configuration and move forward

Comment: Yes. This is there. But,  how does SDL Tridion know where to pick up the ECL Custom DLL from?

Comment: Tricky undocumented question :)

Comment: Actually, those are picked from the following location,
`C:\ProgramData\SDL\SDL Tridion\External Content Library\AddInPipeline\AddIns`
Remember, though you use SDL Web, it still picks up from SDL Tridion folder
Don't forget to mark the answer if this helps resolving your issue

Comment: You are correct about the path. My Custom ECL dll is placed  in - `C:\ProgramData\SDL\SDL Tridion\External Content Library\AddInPipeline\AddIns`, and `ExternalContentLibrary.xml` is under `{Tridion Home}\config\` folder. But, I am not sure how the dll is referred to if it is under a different location and XML under different location. Is is the standard path and SDL will pick it up from this location? That is my real question.

Comment: Ok, as you are trying to understand the concept rather than looking for a quick solution, I have now updated the example code. You can specify the location of the dll as well, but note that the type ="Local File System Provider". For any other type, I believe it will try to look inside the programdata location which I mentioned earlier and will not consider the external path even if specified.

Answer (score 2):

This entry should be in the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file Under `{Tridion Home}\config\` folder.

Search for `extensions` tag. Under that tag you can find the entry for ECL Library. If it is not there then add that entry like below -

```
<extensions>    
<add assemblyFileName="D:\Tridion\bin\Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.TcmExtension.dll" /> 
</extensions>
```

Comment: Yes. This is there. Now, I have an adapter code, which is used to fetch media items from a 3rd party via a service. This is a separate dll, that is also deployed at another location, in the same CM server. Now my question is, how is SDL using it? As I do not see any reference to this custom DLL in any config files. Also it is using the ExternalContentLibrary.xml located in the {Tridion Home}\config\ folder, where the URL for this 3rd party is mentioned.

Comment: Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.TcmExtension.dll - has nothing to do with ECL adapters

Comment: Correct  @YuriBondarchuk ..!! And thank you for giving a clear explanation as well.